# Anyone know how to solve the column ambiguously defined?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   SELECT C.CustomerNo,C.CustomerName,TIMEDIFF(F.ActualTD,F.ActualTA) as DurationOfTime,
        F.FlightDate AS PastTime
   From Flight F,Customer  C,Reservation R
   WHERE C.CustomerNo = R.CustomerNo AND
      R.RouteNo = F.RouteNo AND
      C.CustomerName = 'Ali' AND
      F.FlightDate <= SYSDATE - 1 ;
```

So here I want to find the date which is past and the person who is call Ali, it seems miss something in the code.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *ambiguous* in code you posted:

```
SQL> SELECT c.customerno,
  2         c.customername,
  3         timediff (f.actualtd, f.actualta) AS durationoftime,
  4         f.flightdate AS pasttime
  5    FROM flight f, customer c, reservation r
  6   WHERE     c.customerno = r.customerno
  7         AND r.routeno = f.routeno
  8         AND c.customername = 'Ali'
  9         AND f.flightdate <= SYSDATE - 1;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Query didn't return anything as my *dummy* tables are empty.

---

However, as you tagged the question with an **Oracle** tag, well - there's no function named `TIMEDIFF` in Oracle so either you have your own function with that name, or you used a wrong tag.

Comment: the timediff funtion is i look from the oracle website, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/date-and-time-functions.html#:~:text=TIMEDIFF(expr1%2Cexpr2,46%3A58%3A57.999999%27 as i want to find the distance between two times

Comment: That's a link to **MySQL** documentation, not Oracle. Oracle corp. now *owns* MySQL, but these are different databases.

Comment: OHHH, can i know what is the function for find the distance to the times

Comment: In Oracle? There's none, you'd just subtract who DATE datatype values and - as a result - get **number of days** between them.